# Uno Plaform - WebAssembly-specific sources

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

Are the WebAssembly platform specific sources available somewhere?

Having some weird exceptions/behavior on wasm head when using `HttpClient`/`HttpHandler` (correctly working on standard implemenations on Windows head). Might be (still) CORS related, but not sure how exactly, as the server already allows all origins.

There is a hint path in the exception, probably local to the library build:

```
D:\a\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\runtime\src\libraries\System.Net.Http\src\System\Net\Http\BrowserHttpHandler\BrowserHttpHandler.cs
```

But not much luck when searching this in general:

- Found this: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly, still just only few patches.
- I guess standard .net runtime won't have `BrowserHttpHandler`, will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked file is in fact part of .NET Runtime, see [here on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpHandler.cs).

Uno-specific code is available on the [main repository](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno) and some parts relevant to WASM specifically are in [the bootstrapper repository](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap).